# How to turn off OpenGL filtering when scaling up textures?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, pixel, scaling

I already have these lines in here when I'm loading the texture:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

But when I scale the image here during rendering:

```
glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0454,0.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0454,1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0);
```

I get really bad filtering on the texture (the texture is a spritesheet with multiple frames and I'd rather not make an individual file for each frame).

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it right in terms of texture filtering. However, it's not enough to avoid all  sampling artifacts, especially if you move your sprites. You must also make sure that:

- Your sprites' size in pixels (on the screen) is an integral multiple of the their size in texels (in the texture)
- You draw your sprites at integral coordinates in pixels (or integral-and-a-half, depending on how OpenGL positions texels in textures, I can't remember)

To illustrate the problem, say you have a 32x32 sprite (in the texture) and you map it to a 43x43-pixel quad on screen. Then the GPU only has 32 texels to fill a width of 43 pixels, so it needs to duplicate some of the texels. Exactly which texels are duplicated will depend on the coordinates of your quad on-screen (if you use non-integral coordinates). So moving sprites will appear to have weirdly flickering colors as the GPU decides to duplicate different texels to fill your quad.

To avoid this problem and achieve the best-looking sprites, you really want each texel to map to a single on-screen pixel. If you do this, then using `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` won't matter anymore since every pixel will only use the color from a single texel.

Comment: Is this possible to achieve without putting each frame into a single file? I have the entire image loaded and ready to go

Comment: Yes, it's irrelevant whether there is other stuff in your texture. The important thing is the relation between the size of your sprite in texels and its size in pixels on the screen.

Comment: If you're working in 2D you can get a lot of mileage out of using an orthographic perspective matrix that lets you set your X and Y geometry coordinates to actual pixel values

Comment: While we are on the topic of moving sprites, you might want to mention pre-multiplied alpha. When you use a linear interpolation filter on an alpha blended object nasty things will happen during blending unless you combine color and alpha. It gets really bad when you move objects sub-pixel increments.

Answer (score 1):

You're texture coordinates are pretty confusing to me because they don't form a square or rectangle (you have 3 different X values), nor are you showing the corresponding vertex coordinates (if you aren't interleaving those tex coords with vertex coords, you're just overwriting one texture coordinate over and over).

If you're trying to access a given (square) sub-region of the texture, then I would expect your texCoords to look something like this:

```
float x, float y; // position of the sprite in the texture
float height, float width; // size of the sprite in the texture
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP)
// lower left
glVertex3D(...)
glTexCoord2d(x, y);
// lower right
glVertex3D(...)
glTexCoord2d(x, y + width);
// upper left
glVertex3D(...)
glTexCoord2d(x + height, y);
// upper right
glVertex3D(...)
glTexCoord2d(x + height, y + width);
glEnd()
```

Comment: Yeah, the texture coordinates are not necessarily incorrect, depending on what is in the texture, or if there is some sort of clever squash and stretch behavior going on, but if you want to maintain a 1:1 of source and target pixels to avoid filtering artifacts, you will certainly want to avoid a distorted texture region being applied to a rectangular area onscreen.